# Python - Sum() function for lists of characters

Tags: python, function, sum

I am confused with the `sum` function below:

```
sum([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']],[])
```

The code returns

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Apparently the function is flattening the list. But how do I interpret this usage of `sum` function when the iterable is not numbers and the `start` argument is an empty list? The documentation doesn't seem to explain that.

Comment: Take a look at [Set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

Comment: The `sum()` function uses the `+` operation of whatever the list elements are. For numbers it's addition, for strings it's concatenation, and for lists it's list appending.

Comment: You should not use sum, for such task, as is specified in the documentation

Comment: @Barmar the result of `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']]+[]` is equal to `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']]` not `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` !!!

Comment: The `sum` function does not add two elements, that one is `operator.add`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi `sum()` adds the elements of the list, so it's `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] + ['e'] + []`

Comment: @accdias: what you need here is not set theory but group theory. Lists form a monoid under concatenation, with `[]` being an empty element. Integers form a monoid under addition, with `0` being the empty element. You can make `sum` act on both, because lists also implement addition as concatenation. (It won't work for strings because `sum` needs a mutable accumulator).

Comment: @Barmar note that i've used a nested list !

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I see that, but what does it have to do with the question? The `sum()` function unwraps the list one level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum function here calls the

```
__iadd__():
```

function which basically is extend

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].extend(['e'])
```

This gets done recursively for the array with element **[e]** and then for the 
empty array **[]**
[image: Here is a screen shot of the answer]
I hope this clears your confusion.

`__iadd__():` function is used to implement the **+** operation 
`sum([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']],[])` 
is equivalent to 
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] + ['e'] + []`. 
The last `[]` argument is needed because sum assumes it to be 0, and *we can't add lists and integers*.

Comment: To extend: the `__iadd__` function is used to implement the `+` operation, `sum([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']],[])` is equivalent to `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] + ['e'] + []`. The last `[]` argument is needed because `sum` assumes it to be `0`, and we can't add lists and integers.

Comment: @Joystick can you add 9000's comment to your question. His example I feel is a lot more helpful than the `.extend()` example you currently have.

Comment: This is wrong; it calls `__add__`, not `__iadd__`. It doesn't extend an existing list, it creates a completely new list with each addition.

Comment: @9000 `__iadd__` implements `+=`. `+` is implemented by `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

For lists in Python plus, or +, or `__add__` is overloaded to concatenate lists.

So, it is all a matter of how `__add__` is defined for the elements of the iterable.